# Downloaded package ImportError

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

I have recently installed python 2.17.14 to use a package which I installed in the command prompt with:

```
python -m pip install packageName
```

However, whenever I try to use it with a script provided by the package authors, I get Import Errors:

```
ImportError: cannot import X from YX
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, as I am really new to Python. Does anyone have any ideas?

The package is called neurodesign and I downloaded the try out script from the official website "neuropowertools.org"

Best, 
Max

Comment: What is the import code? You write `from YX import X`?

Comment: Yes: from neurodesign import experiment, optimisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone (who is also new to python^^) fails ridiculously at this task as well: I had to manually install all the modules used within this package for it to work as they weren't installed automatically.